# SpeedRatio & MediaTimeline

Tags: wpf, mediaelement, mediaplayback

I'm trying to be able to affect SpeedRatio on a MediaElement whilst having the media play in a continous loop.

This is possible through code behind; I can reset the position of the media once it has ended, but that creates a seam in the playback.

For seamless playback, I use a MediaTimeline, but when I use I media timeline, I can't change the SpeedRatio.

Has anyone got a different approach to looping playback in a mediaElement, or handling SpeedRatio?

UPDATE:

If I stop the timeline, change the timeline's SpeedRatio, I can produce the result I'm looking for.  The only remaining problem is getting the timeline to start from the same position that it was stopped at.  Pausing the timeline does not allow for the SpeedRatio to be changed.

I still welcome any alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I've found for this is to use XNA to control audio.  It's got a lot more responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

My MediaUriElement in my [open-source](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com) project has a "Loop" property that can provide seemless looping.  Get it from the source because it's the newest.

Comment: I still have a slight pause when it plays back.  The only way I've been able to find a truly seamless loop is by using the MediaTimeline, but then I can't affect the SpeedRatio then.

The Kit is really cool though, thanks for the link.