# Creating audioloop with Media Element

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to loop an mp3 on button press using the mediaElement control as part of a WP7 app. I am using the MediaEnded event handler to reset to the beginning as follows:

{
            mediaElement1.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
            mediaElement1.Play();
}

However, when I do this, I hear a pause each time the clip restarts. How can I loop the background music more seamlessly? When I loop the file in audacity, I don't hear any pause at all.

I am just starting to learn how to program so I apologize if this is a basic question. I searched and could not find an answer to this exact question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem with the mediaElement in WPF.  Unfortunately, I was unable to find a solution to this problem when using the MediaElement.

The only real option for perfect performance would be to use XNA for the audio.

Here's my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276699/speedratio-mediatimeline) around playback, there is one alternative answer, but it didn't help me at the time, it might work for you though